# Unexpected abort when calling treeModelGetRow on a custom GTK/Haskell TreeStore

Tags: haskell, gtk

I'm working on an application in which I'll be displaying some of the data of the application in a TreeView.  Pretty standard.  I'm intending for the display to show data in the main state of the application, a variable stored in a TVar and shared across multiple processes.  So, I am building a CustomView (and only barely understanding how things fit together) that looks into that TVar.

At this time I am doing my testing entirely within `ghci`.

My call to `treeViewGetIter` works correctly.  I have some prints in `treeViewIfaceGetIter` that prints information in the TVar, and all looks okay.  I get back a reasonable iterator if the provided path is valid, and Nothing if the provided path if not.

However, when I pass that iterator to `treeViewGetRow`, the application aborts.  There are no error messages, I'm just kicked back to the command line.  My `ulimit` is set to unlimited, but there is no core dump.

So, here is the setup code:

```
data FileList rowtype = FileList (CustomStore (TVar (Map FilePath (LoadStatus Image))) rowtype)

instance GObjectClass (FileList (LoadStatus Image)) where
    toGObject (FileList cm) = toGObject cm
    unsafeCastGObject = FileList . unsafeCastGObject

instance TypedTreeModelClass FileList
instance TreeModelClass (FileList (LoadStatus Image))

makeStore :: TVar (Map FilePath (LoadStatus Image)) -> IO (FileList (LoadStatus Image))
makeStore tvLst =
    customStoreNew
        tvLst
        FileList
        TreeModelIface {
              treeModelIfaceGetFlags = return [TreeModelListOnly]
            , treeModelIfaceGetIter = \[n] ->
                atomically $ do
                    unsafeIOToSTM $ putStrLn $ "Seeking element " ++ show n
                    var <- readTVar tvLst
                    unsafeIOToSTM $ putStrLn $ "tvar info: " ++ (show $ M.size var)
                    if M.null var || M.size var < n
                        then return Nothing
                        else return $ Just $ TreeIter 0 (fromIntegral n) 0 0
            , treeModelIfaceGetPath = \(TreeIter _ n _ _) -> return [fromIntegral n]
            , treeModelIfaceGetRow = \(TreeIter _ n _ _) ->
                atomically $ do
                    unsafeIOToSTM $ putStrLn $ "Looking up row at " ++ show n
                    var <- readTVar tvLst
                    return (M.elems var !! fromIntegral n)
            , treeModelIfaceIterNext = \a -> do
                putStrLn "treeModelIFaceIterNext"
                return Nothing
            , treeModelIfaceIterChildren = \a -> do
                putStrLn "treeModelIfaceIterChildren"
                return Nothing
            , treeModelIfaceIterHasChild = \a -> do
                putStrLn "treeModelIfaceIterHasChild"
                return False
            , treeModelIfaceIterNChildren = \a -> do
                putStrLn "treeModelIfaceIterNChildren"
                return 0
            , treeModelIfaceIterNthChild = \a b -> do
                putStrLn "treeModelIfaceIterNthChild"
                return Nothing
            , treeModelIfaceIterParent = \a -> do
                putStrLn "treeModelIfaceIterParent"
                return Nothing
            , treeModelIfaceRefNode = \a -> do
                putStrLn "treeModelIfaceRefNode"
                return ()
            , treeModelIfaceUnrefNode = \a -> do
                putStrLn "treeModelIfaceUnrefNode"
                return ()
            }
        Nothing
        Nothing
```

And then, here is an interaction.  tv was initialized with three entries, and st was initialized via `makeStore tv`:

```
*Main FileListModel Control.Concurrent.STM Control.Monad> :t tv
tv
  :: TVar
       (containers-0.5.0.0:Data.Map.Base.Map
          FilePath (LoadStatus Alyra.Photos.Image.Image))
*Main FileListModel Control.Concurrent.STM Control.Monad> :t st
st :: FileList (LoadStatus Alyra.Photos.Image.Image)
*Main FileListModel Control.Concurrent.STM Control.Monad> atomically (Data.Map.size `liftM` readTVar tv)
3
*Main FileListModel Control.Concurrent.STM Control.Monad> Just iter <- treeModelGetIter st [0]
Seeking element 0
tvar info: 3
*Main FileListModel Control.Concurrent.STM Control.Monad> iter
TreeIter (-288664969) 0 0 0
*Main FileListModel Control.Concurrent.STM Control.Monad> v <- treeModelGetRow st iter
```

After that last command, I'm back in bash without any errors and no indication as to why the program crashed.

I have not exhaustively checked them, but the other functions seem to work.

I made one additional change to the declaration above:

```
        , treeModelIfaceGetRow = \n -> do
            putStrLn $ "treeModelGetRow " ++ show n
            return Loading
```

Even now, when there is no interaction with the underlying tvar, I get the same crash.

So, how do I diagnose this kind of error?  I actually have no idea how to start since it's an interaction between C and Haskell.  And, for that matter, is there anything obvious that I've done wrong that GTK requires?

(for the record, I called initGUI before setting up the TreeStore, but that part isn't included here)